# Float left vs float right - why does the order change?

Tags: html, css

HTML :

```
<img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-lUl0ztniLKk/Vhhjg7WWPJI/AAAAAAAAAJI/PgYEmoSNKRU/s400/Author.gif" alt="Author photo">
<p class="author-text">Jackson Gonzalez</p>
```

CSS:

```
 img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.author-text {
    font-size: 22px;
    float: left;
}
```

If i have float left, the order makes sense to me.. because first the image then the text.  But when I change float from left to right.. first the text shows up then the image?.. why does the order change?...

Left: https://codepen.io/psj01/pen/YrgKLy
Right: https://codepen.io/psj01/pen/KXEPoQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are both left, the image is pushed left first then the text is pushed left like you said.  This is the same for the right.  The image is pushed all the way to the right, and then the text is pushed to the right, basically bumping into the image.

The first item gets pushed in it's respective direction first, then the second item follows.  You are basically just reversing the direction when you change the float to right.  They move individually in the direction of the float in the order that they are laid out in the CSS but do not pass each other.

Answer (score 2):

`float: right` simply reverses the horizontal order in comparison to `float: left`, similar to a language that's written from right to left. The first item is aligned right, the next one follows in right-to-left order, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the positioning of the content in the HTML file, CSS will place the first item listed to the furthest point specified. It you want both items to be to the right, but the image to come first (being placed to the left of the text), you can try one of two options. First, simply place the p tag before the image tag in your HTML, like such:

```
<p class="author-text">Jackson Gonzalez</p>

<img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-
lUl0ztniLKk/Vhhjg7WWPJI/AAAAAAAAAJI/PgYEmoSNKRU/s400/Author.gif" 
alt="Author photo">
```

Or you can place both elements inside of a div tag, keeping the same float left properties on them, but then float the entire div container to the right. Like this:

**HTML File**

```
  <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-lUl0ztniLKk/Vhhjg7WWPJI/AAAAAAAAAJI/PgYEmoSNKRU/s400/Author.gif" alt="Author photo">

  <p class="author-text">Jackson Gonzalez</p>

<div>
```

**CSS File**

```
div {
  float: right;
} 

img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.author-text {
    font-size: 22px;
    float: left;
}
```

I tried both of these options out in your code pen link. Play around with using the div as a container to position objects. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Sequence 1 was because img element was firstly rendered and held the far left position firstly before the text;

Sequence 2 was because of the same reason: img element was firstly rendered and held the far-right position firstly before the text.